# How to check which add-on(s) in Firefox is disabling e10s on Arch?

Tags: arch-linux, configuration, firefox

On Arch Linux with GNOME 3.24.2 and Firefox 53.0.3 (soon to be upgraded to 54 when it comes into the repository) I have found in my `about:support` section that it says:

```
Multiprocess Windows    0/1 (Disabled by add-ons)
```

So I was wondering if there is any way that I can check which add-on(s) is doing this?

Comment: I can't find a profile of my where it's enabled. Even in a new blank profile with just "Ubuntu Modifications" 3.2 it shows as "Disabled by add-ons".

And ... disabling that enables Multiprocess windows. Interesting.

Comment: Try a new blank profile. If your distro or Firefox package includes any all-users add-ons (like Ubuntu does) they might be to blame.

Comment: Ubuntu Modifications is well known for disabling e10s. One of the core priciples of Arch is that it comes straight from upstream with the least distro-specific modifications possible, so nothing is pre-installed in Firefox.

Comment: I have learnt something!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Multiprocess Windows is listed as "Disabled by add-ons", open `about:addons` and disable all your add-ons, then enable them one-by-one to find which add-on is disabling e10s. Although Firefox will not allow incompatible add-ons to load - add-ons can be incompatible with e10s and thus their developers have chosen to disable e10s while their add-on is enabled.

Comment: How do I know which add-on is compatible and which is not? Do I just have to manually go through it and check by disabling them all and then enabling one-by-one?

Comment: Add-ons incompatible with the current version aren't started, so I'm unclear how they would affect multiprocess capability.

Comment: Found the one causing the issue! Thanks! :)

Comment: Which one was it?

Comment: @JoeP: VTzilla, the VirusTotal add-on.

Comment: Out of interest was it "incompatible with the current version"? And/or already disabled?

Comment: @JoeP: No, it was compatible. If it weren't compatible then Firefox wouldn't have allowed it to load. Its compatibility is stated on the add-on search page where compatibility with the current version is one of the filters. Some add-ons just for some reason don't work with e10s so they choose to disable it.

Comment: I have now disabled and e10s have reactivated.

Comment: In my case, it was the [WordReference Translator add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/wordreference-translator/)

Answer (score 6):

Try the official [add-on-compatibility-reporter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-on-compatibility-reporter/), it lists the compatible addons.